Why SSD accessing internal HD finds home folder empty?
I have two hard drives sda2, sdb2, and one SSD on system.  sdb2 runs windows and the remaining use opensuse which ssd has the latest version.  When I use Dolphin on SSD to mount hard drives (HD), I have no problem with mounting.  sdb2 is accessible and its contents (files).  When I access sda2, the suse files are visible but home folder is empty inside (should have data files in it).  I checked etc/fstab in sda2 and I found partition (Btrfs) to be the same for both ssd and sda2 and home folder is listed like this:
 /home                   btrfs  subvol=/@/home                0  0

Therefore, I attempted to mount manually like this,
sudo mount /dev/sda2 -o subvol=/@/home

and I get the following error message
Can't find in /etc/fstab

What steps I am missing in my attempts to mount? How do I access home folder in sda2?

Your /etc/fstab line is malformed: it should have 6 fields separated by whitespace, not 5. It is missing the device name/volume label/UUID field at the beginning. Your sudo mount /dev/sda2 -o subvol=/@/home is missing the mount point location: where is the subvolume of /dev/sda2 supposed to be mounted? If you don't specify all the required information on the command line, the mount command will look for a matching line in /etc/fstab to fill in missing information, but cannot find one.

@telcoM,  my /etc/fstab has name/volume/uuid field.  I did not posted it because I did not considered it relevant for discussion.   Yes, you are correct, I did not specify the mount point location.  I do not know where it is supposed to be mounted.  I am guessing it is something like " /mnt/data "?  If I add it, then what?

@user429323 If you want help, then your question needs to have all of the information. Not including some of it renders it more difficult to see what's going on and to help. If it has that field, then edit the question and add it so that people can see what it is.

Using suggestions from @telcoM, I solved my problem. I have to write a complete command line that includes mount point as follows:

sudo mount /dev/sda2 -o subvol=/@/home /mnt/data1

Before doing that, I had to make sure that data1 folder is created in /mnt folder of the SSD.  Then click on HD listed in Dolphin application.  The home folder and its contest is listed there.   To avoid writing the command every time I want to access HD, I have to make an icon on desktop screen with the above sudo command.

If you add a line /dev/sda2 /mnt/data1 btrfs noauto,subvol=/@/home 0 0 to /etc/fstab, you can simplify the mount command to just sudo mount /dev/sda2 or sudo mount /mnt/data1 (both will work). If you add user to the options field (i.e. user,noauto,subvol=/@/home) you may even be able to omit the sudo part, if your mount command has the setuid root permission set, but the user option brings some extra constraints you might want to override in some cases.
